# How do you find the source of a related_name in Django in large codebases?

Tags: django, django-models

Take these two models for example (pseudo code)

```
class House():
    Pass

class Cat():
     house = Foreignkey(to=House, related_name=“cats”)
```

Now say if this is a massive codebase that I’m not familiar with with these definitions in different files. I see an instance of House being called with the method “cats”

```
house1.cats
```

And I want to investigate and see where cats came from. But when I go to the definition of House, there is no mention of cats. There is no way I can figure this out just by looking at House, and names are not always as simple to follow as this example(sometimes the related name is not similar to the class name). I do use fuzzy finding and search for `related_name=cat` In the codebase and that usually works, but it does not work for models where the related_name was generated through an base class such as

```
class Base(models.Model):
    m2m = models.ManyToManyField(
        OtherModel,
        related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_related",
        related_query_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)ss",
    )
```

It’ll be basically impossible to figure out what model is the source of relation other than hunting it down manually by looking at every single file, which is quite difficult in a large codebase. I’ve used Rails and you always have to define these relations both ways in both models so they are easy to follow. I find it odd that in Django both sides of the relationship are defined in one model. Am I missing something ?

My question is, is there a way or workflow to figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able call `house1.cats.model` and get it to show you the model it is referring to